# What makes the optimizer insert a sort operator in the plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sort-operator

What are the reasons that the optimizer chooses to insert a sort operator in the plan (to satisfy a stream aggregate or a merge join, etc.) instead of going for hash match or hash join?

I have now see a couple of examples where it obviously makes a mistake and hinting the query will make it a lot faster.

The examples I have seen are from SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the reasons that the optimizer chooses to insert a sort operator in the plan (to satisfy a stream aggregate or a merge join, etc.) instead of going for hash match or hash join?

It's a cost-based query optimizer that estimates the cost of a candidate plan based on the available statistics.  Statistics may be missing or out-of-date, and even with good statistics the cost estimation process is not perfect.

So the reason is simply that based on the available statistics, it estimated that that was the cheaper plan.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the answer. Even after UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN this happens but I guess your answer covers this senario also. Is the only fix then to use a hint?

Comment: Statistics and be missing as well as out-of-date.  Also there may be missing indexes.